# hyperref not linking index pages

Tags: hyperref, indexing, imakeidx

Compiling the following MWE with **lualatex** with makeindex, my index renders with no hyperlinks for page numbers:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} 
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at quam libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. \index{Donec} nulla diam, dignissim sed ligula et, mattis efficitur augue. Ut vel rutrum lacus. Nulla sed lorem vel lacus convallis pharetra. Phasellus fermentum arcu eget magna placerat, sit amet egestas enim viverra. Integer eu ex mollis nisi ultrices congue sed eget nunc. Duis sed ipsum eu ligula hendrerit placerat.

    Etiam vitae massa in magna \index{hendrerit} pharetra. Vestibulum lectus purus, rutrum at sollicitudin eu, dignissim quis diam. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum commodo justo vitae pretium fermentum. Donec ornare pulvinar ligula non ultrices. Nullam at rutrum nunc, a volutpat metus. Aliquam id velit varius massa feugiat malesuada congue at dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc quis magna nisi. \index{Vestibulum} efficitur justo turpis, eget ultricies sem iaculis in. Nulla sit amet urna lorem. Sed magna elit, fringilla in augue sit amet, pellentesque semper nunc. Mauris enim urna, dictum vel nisi vehicula, congue euismod ligula. 

    Morbi consectetur efficitur purus, vel vestibulum risus hendrerit nec. Curabitur mattis dolor eget lorem imperdiet, id maximus massa porttitor. Vivamus sit amet urna ut est fringilla porta ac sed leo. Nunc ac lectus ullamcorper, accumsan dolor dictum, tincidunt quam. Praesent condimentum ultricies magna, at placerat neque molestie sit amet. Vivamus a nisl et sapien imperdiet finibus eget vitae nulla. Curabitur semper sem non leo elementum, vitae lobortis massa cursus. Pellentesque sodales rutrum tempus.

    In ut purus elementum, scelerisque mauris pellentesque, pretium nisl. Sed eget luctus nisl, eu accumsan nisl. Phasellus purus erat, blandit nec odio a, rutrum ultrices mauris. Proin interdum justo eget mollis volutpat. Donec tellus diam, scelerisque sit amet laoreet eget, tristique ac magna. Aliquam posuere commodo nulla, sit amet vehicula sapien efficitur eu. Maecenas vel elit facilisis, aliquet elit sit amet, euismod augue. Donec ac risus porttitor, vulputate ex ut, finibus ipsum. Pellentesque aliquam ac nisi sit amet luctus. Mauris cursus facilisis egestas. Cras \index{vulputate} nunc purus, id dictum mi tincidunt vel. Morbi finibus tortor mauris, a sagittis justo luctus ut. In lobortis felis vel lorem mollis cursus. Curabitur sit amet iaculis purus. Proin ac dolor non nibh ultricies facilisis.

    Nulla consectetur eget sapien in pulvinar. Mauris sollicitudin ornare lorem, ut auctor magna imperdiet nec. Donec et nibh ipsum. Curabitur a tortor condimentum turpis pretium ornare. Vivamus quis feugiat nisl. Curabitur at rutrum lorem, sit amet consequat neque. Duis \index{convallis} a ipsum sit amet sodales. Sed eleifend feugiat aliquam. Morbi efficitur est odio, vel sagittis mi condimentum sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas vulputate dapibus leo vel ornare. In fermentum libero nulla, vitae faucibus quam scelerisque venenatis.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Looking at the `.idx` file, the list items are showing as `\item ABCDE, ##` instead of `\item ABCDE, \hyperpage{##}`.

Are there some package clashes in my preamble?

If that could matter, `texindy` returns `ERROR: Opening file "./FILE.ind" failed!` for the same file.

Comment: This has actually nothing to do with `lualatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hyperref` does a lot of 'severe' redefinitions of commands, so it's basically the package which has to be the **last** one (apart from some exceptions) in the preamble.

Changing the order in which `\usepackage{imakeidx}` and `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}` are specified in the preamble works.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} 
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at quam libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. \index{Donec} nulla diam, dignissim sed ligula et, mattis efficitur augue. Ut vel rutrum lacus. Nulla sed lorem vel lacus convallis pharetra. Phasellus fermentum arcu eget magna placerat, sit amet egestas enim viverra. Integer eu ex mollis nisi ultrices congue sed eget nunc. Duis sed ipsum eu ligula hendrerit placerat.

    Etiam vitae massa in magna \index{hendrerit} pharetra. Vestibulum lectus purus, rutrum at sollicitudin eu, dignissim quis diam. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum commodo justo vitae pretium fermentum. Donec ornare pulvinar ligula non ultrices. Nullam at rutrum nunc, a volutpat metus. Aliquam id velit varius massa feugiat malesuada congue at dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc quis magna nisi. \index{Vestibulum} efficitur justo turpis, eget ultricies sem iaculis in. Nulla sit amet urna lorem. Sed magna elit, fringilla in augue sit amet, pellentesque semper nunc. Mauris enim urna, dictum vel nisi vehicula, congue euismod ligula. 

    Morbi consectetur efficitur purus, vel vestibulum risus hendrerit nec. Curabitur mattis dolor eget lorem imperdiet, id maximus massa porttitor. Vivamus sit amet urna ut est fringilla porta ac sed leo. Nunc ac lectus ullamcorper, accumsan dolor dictum, tincidunt quam. Praesent condimentum ultricies magna, at placerat neque molestie sit amet. Vivamus a nisl et sapien imperdiet finibus eget vitae nulla. Curabitur semper sem non leo elementum, vitae lobortis massa cursus. Pellentesque sodales rutrum tempus.

    In ut purus elementum, scelerisque mauris pellentesque, pretium nisl. Sed eget luctus nisl, eu accumsan nisl. Phasellus purus erat, blandit nec odio a, rutrum ultrices mauris. Proin interdum justo eget mollis volutpat. Donec tellus diam, scelerisque sit amet laoreet eget, tristique ac magna. Aliquam posuere commodo nulla, sit amet vehicula sapien efficitur eu. Maecenas vel elit facilisis, aliquet elit sit amet, euismod augue. Donec ac risus porttitor, vulputate ex ut, finibus ipsum. Pellentesque aliquam ac nisi sit amet luctus. Mauris cursus facilisis egestas. Cras \index{vulputate} nunc purus, id dictum mi tincidunt vel. Morbi finibus tortor mauris, a sagittis justo luctus ut. In lobortis felis vel lorem mollis cursus. Curabitur sit amet iaculis purus. Proin ac dolor non nibh ultricies facilisis.

    Nulla consectetur eget sapien in pulvinar. Mauris sollicitudin ornare lorem, ut auctor magna imperdiet nec. Donec et nibh ipsum. Curabitur a tortor condimentum turpis pretium ornare. Vivamus quis feugiat nisl. Curabitur at rutrum lorem, sit amet consequat neque. Duis \index{convallis} a ipsum sit amet sodales. Sed eleifend feugiat aliquam. Morbi efficitur est odio, vel sagittis mi condimentum sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas vulputate dapibus leo vel ornare. In fermentum libero nulla, vitae faucibus quam scelerisque venenatis.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]